# display files which starts with specific set of letters in Linux/Unix

Tags: linux

I want to list with details all files which starts which letter f,g,h or s and ends with **.conf** in the directory **/etc**

I tried as following:

```
ls -l /etc | awk '/[fghs]*.conf/'
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too much work. This works under most shells:

```
ls -l /etc/[fghs]*.conf
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works if I'm already in the /etc directory, I want to execute this even if I'm in another directory.

Comment: So then put "/etc/" in front, just as normal.

Comment: yes, I already tried that but it lists all the files in the /etc directory, this is the command I tried : `ls -l /etc [fghs]*.conf`

Comment: That... there... *sigh*